# Is there any way to configure logstash to ignore failures for a particular output plugin?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have a logstash pipeline where logs are transferred to my log server and stored on disk there (highest priority). Logs are then indexed in elasticsearch on a separate server (lowest priority). I realized today that in the event elasticsearch becomes unreachable, the entire pipeline gets compromised, and I can't risk something stopping the logs from being stored on disk.

How do I tell logstash to ignore errors with a particular output plugin, for instance connection errors for elasticsearch?

**UPDATE**

My current setup starts with a lumberjack input accepting forwarded logs from all other instances. Then the files go untouched to a file output (highest priority). Then, everything goes through their specific filters (syslog, nginx, etc.). And finally, filtered logs make their way to an elasticsearch output (lowest priority) where each log type is indexed in its own index.

Having read a little of the logstash documentation, I know that errors with the pipeline, anywhere in the pipeline, can compromise other plugins.

Comment: Do you mind sharing a bit more about your current configuration(s) and topology?

Comment: @Val added an update

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've done:
    (client)->Logstash->File<-Logstash->Elasticsearch

which seems like your way of trying to use the files as a broker in case of problems.

Here are 2.5 alternatives:

1. run two logstash processes - one to receive logs from the client and write them to files, and second to read the files and write them to elasticsearch.  You're still at risk of other things compromising this flow (like running out of disk space, etc).
2. use a real broker like redis or rabbitmq.  For my transient data that would be lost if not processed (snmptrap, syslog), I run a small logstash that takes that input and writes it to redis.  A second logstash reads from redis and applies all the logstash magic.
3. use a better shipper, if possible.  Filebeat (the replacement for logstash-forwarder, aka lumberjack), for example, will stop sending logs when it detects back-pressure from logstash.  This gives you a distributed cache, for free.  This isn't possible with some inputs (see #2), of course.

Comment: Well, the logs being stored on file are necessary for the time being since there are a bunch of intermediate scripts that process those files (believe me, I tried to work around this) before they're ultimately uploaded to S3. I like the idea of #1 since there's not much happening on the log server besides dealing with logs (one more process won't hurt). Can you explain what you mean by #3? I'm not aware of the pros/cons of using filebeat over lumberjack.

Comment: For #2, I'd mention [Kafka](http://kafka.apache.org) as an option as well. A really serious distributed log solution.

Comment: filebeat is the replacement for logstash-forwarder (aka lumberjack).